How do I use Core Location in Apple Watch preview canvas?
Xcode 16, bare-bones watch-only project, default settings. Made sure NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription is present in Info.plist. Requesting with requestWhenInUseAuthorization. Works completely fine in the standalone simulator, but not in the preview canvas. Most interestingly, I do hear an alert ding, but the alert isn't shown.
I'm new to Xcode, is this expected? That system alerts get swallowed in previews? If it is, is there a way to pre-approve location usage, maybe via simctl?
